# Синонимичны ли контекстуально слова "жареный" и "опасный"?

Tags: перевод, выражения, idioms, контекст

> Семецкий, чуя, что дело пахнет **жареным**, сказал, что будет спать в дальней комнате, потому что оттуда лучше вид. Вид, как же! Поверил я в этот вид, наверняка он просто рассчитывал удрать, спрыгнув вниз, на ржавые крыши пристроек. Будь моя воля, я посоветовал бы ему это сделать, не дожидаясь оказии, просто так, профилактически.

Значит ли в этом контексте слово **жареный** то же, что **опасный**?

Comment: Семецкий — это тоже в каком-то смысле идиома. О нем можно почитать (здесь) [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Дело] пахнет/запахло жареным** – это фразеологизм, который означает «опасно, рискованно», синонимы: *пахнет порохом*, *пахнет керосином*, *пахнет палёным*.

Answer (score 5):

запахло жареным
• ПАХНЕТ/ЗАПАХЛО ЖАРЕНЫМ highly coll

## [VP; impers]

1. sth. promises profit:

   - it (sth.) smells of money;
   - there's money to be made.
     ♦ У этого спекулянта большие связи, он всегда знает, где пахнет жареным. This speculator has good connections and always knows where there's money to be made.
2. Also: ПАХНЕТ/ЗАПАХЛО ПАЛЕНЫМ highly coll danger from or punishment for some wrongdoing, illegal actions etc is imminent:

   - one smells trouble (coming);
   - there's danger in the air;
   - it looks like they've got me (you etc );
   - it looks like the jig is up.
     ♦ "Так, - сказал Губошлёп, не утрачивая своей загадочной весёлости. - Что-то палёным пахнет" (Шукшин 1). "Damn," said Fat Lip, without losing his enigmatic gaiety. "It looks like they've got us" (1a).

В данном контексте речь идёт о грозящей Семецкому ОПАСНОСТИ.

In this context we are talking about DANGER.

Comment: Это правильно, что Вы упомянули оба значения, но стоит также указать, что (2) в наше время употребляется намного чаще.